# Convert a gRPC trailer to an error object in Go

Tags: go, grpc

I receive errors from a gRPC call as a trailer and I want to convert it to an error object in Go. My problem is that the returned object is of type string and I can't find anyway to convert it to an error object.

Maybe an error object is the wrong approach, I really only want to be able to display the errors in a nice formatted way to the end user.

My test code in Go looks like this:

```
_, e := client.CreatePayment(ctx, addPayment, grpc.Trailer(&trailer))

if e != nil {
    stringError := trailer.Get("errors-bin")
    fmt.Println(stringError)

    return "", e
}
```

And the printed string looks like this:

```
[
N
L
result.message↕string.min_len→*value length must be at least 1 characters]
```

Java code that solves this problem looks like this:

```
Metadata trailers = e.getTrailers();
if(trailers != null) {
    ErrorsProto.Errors errors = e.getTrailers().get(ProtoUtils.keyForProto(ErrorsProto.Errors.getDefaultInstance()));
    if(errors != null) {
        System.out.println(errors);
    }
}
```

Comment: [`errors.New`](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#New)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with some help from a friend :)

```
    stringError := trailer.Get("errors-bin")
    byteError := []byte(stringError[0])

    var result common.Errors

    _ = proto.Unmarshal(byteError, &result)

    err := result.GetErrors()

    fmt.Println(err)
```

common.Errors is created by PROTOC from a errors.proto file.